# problems with setcap in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am using command in my code to compile my server.

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' ./server
```

previously I was getting no error while I was using ubuntu 12.04 LTS but now while using ubuntu 14.04 LTS I get " Error on binding: Permission denied"

Can anyone guide me what do do in such case

Comment: I can confirm that I still get this error on 14.04 - my use case is for running server on port 80.